# What is the difference between $element.on("$destroy", fn) and $scope.$on("$destroy", fn) in terms of their role in the digest cycle?

Tags: angularjs

I was refactoring my code base from this:

```
$rootScope.$on('broadcastedEvent', function() {
  doThings(); 
});
// nothing else is done
```

To this:

```
var deregisterFn = $rootScope.$on('broadcastedEvent', function() {
  doThings(); 
});

$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
  deregisterFn();
});
```

And in somewhere in the code(completely unrelated to my first example), I noticed that it is implemented differently like this:

```
var deregisterFn = $rootScope.$on('broadcastedEvent', function() {
  doThings(); 
});

$element.on('$destroy', function() {
  deregisterFn();
});
```

How different are $element.on("$destroy", fn) and $scope.$on("$destroy", fn)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If scope is attached to element `element.$on('destroy')` and `$scope.$on('$destroy')` do same things.

But if not there are difference. E.g. not all elements have own scope:

```
<div ng-if=""> // has scope
  <div> // no own scope
    <div some-directive-without-scope> // no own scope, you can inject $element, $scope in directive here but they are not bound to each other
```

Also I want to notice, that if you broadcast some event on $rootScope:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('myEvent')
```

Usual way to listen to it is:

```
$scope.$on('broadcastedEvent', function() {
  doThings(); 
});
```

And here you do not need to deregister anything - all $on handlers are removed when scope is destroyed.